# Retrofit2 - having issues sending POSt request to API

Tags: java, android, api, post, retrofit

I would really really appreciate any help I can get on this! Sorry for the long question.

I'm creating this android app, where to sign up, users will type in their phone number and submit it, to get a verification code via text message.

I have worked off of this tutorial:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sending-data-with-retrofit-2-http-client-for-android--cms-27845

I have reduced the 2 fields in their app to one field - one text field for a phone number, and a submit button below. This phone number is to be sent to the API.

I'm really new to Retrofit, and I've been trying for a while now to successfully send a call to the API. I have tested the API call by using the 'Postman' desktop app, and the API is alive and responding...I've just not been able to form a valid request to send to the API.

The JSON schema our API guy designed...for this activity needs just one string, the phone number:

```
{
  "phone_number": "string"
}
```

and then if it is a valid phone number and the user isn't in the database, you get back a 200 response

```
    {
    "message": "string"
    }
```

OR you can get back a 400 response from the API

```
{
  "error": "string",
  "description": "string"
}
```

My retrofit interface, called APIService.java looks like this:

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface APIService {

    @POST("/verifications/signup/send")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<Post> sendPhoneNumber(@Field("phone_number") String phone_number);
}
```

I am really new to retrofit2, and above, I can sense one issue, which I don't know how to solve. From the API schema I was given, this one parameter I sent to the API should be 'body'....not 'field'. Maybe in retrofit @Body...I am not too sure how to implement that in this java file above.

Now, what I did below might be really stupid...I don't understand how retrofit java 'model' classes should be made. I followed one tutorial that modeled the class after the RESPONSE, rather than the data call. So, I modified their Post class (which is what I called my ?JSON object to send a single phone number). So my Post class looks like this:

```
public class Post {

    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //return "Post{" + "message = " + message + '}';
        return "This is a return message string";
    }
}
```

Honestly, I think what I've done might be totally wrong, but I am not sure how to design the object(Post) class, considering I don't even know what this class will be used for...except getting the response back?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private TextView mResponseTv;
    private APIService mAPIService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText phoneNumberEt = (EditText) 
findViewById(R.id.et_phoneNumber);

        Button submitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
        mResponseTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_response);

        mAPIService = ApiUtils.getAPIService();

        submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            String phoneNumber = phoneNumberEt.getText().toString().trim();
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNumber)) {
                sendPost(phoneNumber);
            }
        }
    });
}

public void sendPost(String phone_number) {
    mAPIService.sendPhoneNumber(phone_number).enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {

            int statusCode = response.code();

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                showResponse("Response code is " + statusCode + ". Submitted successfully to API - " + response.body().toString());
                Log.i(TAG, "post submitted to API." + response.body().toString());
            }
        }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {

                showResponse("Unable to submit post to API.");
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to submit post to API.");
            }
        });
    }

    public void showResponse(String response) {
        if (mResponseTv.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            mResponseTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        mResponseTv.setText(response);
    }

}
```

My other files are pretty much exactly like the files in the tutorial link above. That's what I modified to get to my simple one text field version.

When I am able to get this to contact the API, and I can read the response, then I'll incorporate this into the real app I'm working on.

For now, the app compliles, and runs on my phone(and emulator too). When I submit the phone number, the text field below the submit button doesn't show any message like it should...so I know for sure that theres a problem once

```
mAPIService.sendPhoneNumber(phone_number).enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) 
{
```

is reached in MainActivity.

Comment: Use can use this site for create a model class for retrofit..   http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: in postman are you sending form data or raw data

Comment: in postman I am sending

100.60.100.48:8080/api/v1/verifications/signup/send?phone_number=1112223334

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this api requires parameters in JsonObject. so try this

In your APIService

```
@POST("/verifications/signup/send")

Call<JsonObject> sendPhoneNumber(@Body JsonObject phone_number);
```

And when sending data use this

```
JsonObject object=new JsonObject();

object.addProperty("phone_number",yourPhoneNumber);
```

and in your send post method

```
mAPIService.sendPhoneNumber(object).enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {

            int statusCode = response.code();

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                showResponse("Response code is " + statusCode + ". Submitted successfully to API - " + response.body().toString());
                Log.i(TAG, "post submitted to API." + response.body().toString());
            }
        }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {

                showResponse("Unable to submit post to API.");
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to submit post to API.");
            }
        });
    }
```

Please try and let me know if it is working.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your time and effort..I tried exactly what you suggest above...no response. How about that Post.java file...your solution doesnt use it...don't we need some sort of 'model' class? I am not sure if the sending JSON objects is the right idea though. This is a snapshot of the API specs

https://ibb.co/dyb5SH

Comment: @Hideyoshi If we are not getting the response than whats the use of creating model class. First check if you are getting the response right with the method I provided above than we will work on creating model class.

Comment: Thank you. This lead to it working.The other issue that was causing a problem was that Retrofit had an issue with my base url ending with a forward slash. So i found out that when retrofit is having issues connecting to the API, investigate the forward slashes at the end of the base url and at the begining of the specific request url. Thanks for all your help @AbhayBohra

Comment: I am glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

According to the JSON schema with the phone number, you need to pass the phone number in the body of the API. Instead of using a @Field annotation, use a @Body annotation where the parameter will be an instance of the RequestBody class.

@Field documentation https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Field.html

Create the new RequestBody class with field phone number.

```
public class RequestBody {

   @Expose
   @SerializedName("phone_number")
   private String phoneNumber;

   public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
   this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
   }

   public String getPhoneNumber() {
   return phoneNumber;
   }
```

From the activity when you want to pass the phone number, create an object of the RequestBody class, pass the phone number in the setPhoneNumber() method. Then pass this object in the APIService as a parameter.

In MainActivity.class,

```
public void sendPost(String phone_number) {

RequestBody requestBody = new RequestBody();
requestBody.setPhoneNumber(phone_number);
mAPIService.sendPhoneNumber(requestBody).enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) 
{
```

Your APIService will thus look like

```
public interface APIService {

    @POST("/verifications/signup/send")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<Post> sendPhoneNumber(@Body RequestBody requestBody);
}
```